# BadMethodCallException Method [validate] does not exist

Tags: validation, authentication, laravel-5, methods

furture more it says.

> in Controller.php line 82.

```
at Controller->__call('validate', array(object(Request), array('email' => 'required|string', 'password' => 'required|string')))
in AuthenticatesUsers.php line 63
```

**note:** 
every thing was working fine till yesterday morning.my laravel version is 5.4.36.

Answer (score 1):

Put this line in your class

```
 use ValidatesRequests;
```

Right below

```
 class classname ...... {
   use ValidatesRequests;
 }
```

Comment: in which class i need to add these login or base or in authenticatesusers

Comment: @DJEntertainment the class in which you are using `validate` method.

Comment: yesterday i global php version 7.3 before 5.6 was global do that have any effect??

Answer (score 0):

Your `LoginController` doesn't extend from the base Controller, `App\Http\Controllers\Controller` or this base class is missing a trait. This class was setup to use the `Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests` trait, which gives you the `validate` method.

If your base Controller does not use this trait, then you can add the use statement to use this trait so that you will have the `validate` method in all your Controllers.

Comment: can u  kindly remotly have a look on my project for few mints.it would be a great help for me

Comment: If your `LoginController` extends that base Controller you should have the `validate` method, so it would mean that you are incorrect in assuming this Controller throwing the error extends from the base Controller mentioned in the answer, or that base Controller does not use the trait mentioned

Comment: class LoginController extends Controller this copied from my login controller besides that validate method is also there

Comment: protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            $this->username() => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);
    }

Comment: this is validate method can u check for me if there is any error

Comment: what ever controller is causing this error does not extend from a controller that uses the `ValidatesRequests` trait ... I can only assume this is the `LoginController` because the error mentions the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait which is only used in the `LoginController`